# Elastic search query to find status code by time

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am new to elastic search.
How do I write a query like below

Select count(1)c , status_code
From
Index-b2b-api
Where api-proxy-name = 'some-b2b-api'
Group by status_code

Thanks

Comment: hey @hemanth, was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
GET Index-b2b-api/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_status_code
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": { "api-proxy-name": "some-b2b-api" }
      }
   }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_status_code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "status_code"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will give you something like

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "by_status_code": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "200",
          "doc_count": 5950
        },
        {
          "key": "404",
          "doc_count": 330
        },
        {
          "key": "503",
          "doc_count": 208
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```